# jsplumb when object is cloned and then dragged in containment

Tags: jquery, jsplumb

I'm trying to drag the black object in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8AgQD/61/) into the blue box.
I create a clone of the black object and once it's placed in the blue area,
I'm adding jsplumb connectors to it and I want to be able to drag it again only
within the blue area. It doesn't seem to work. Can someone please tell me where the problem is and if I'm including the right libraries. The black box is contained in the blue area only the first time and not after that.
Thanks

`js`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#drop").append("<div id='con' class='container'></div>");
        var x = null;
    $(".draggable").draggable({
        helper: 'clone',
        cursor: 'pointer',
        tolerance: 'fit',
        clone: true,
        containment: '.container',
        obstacle: '.draggable',
        preventCollision: true,
        revert: true
    });

    $("#drop").droppable({
        accept: '.draggable',
        containment: '.container',
        drop: function (e, ui) {
            if ($(ui.draggable)[0].id != "") {
                x = ui.helper.clone();
                ui.helper.remove();             
                jsPlumb.draggable(x, {
                //x.draggable({
                    containment: '.container',
                    drop: function (event, ui) {    
                        jsPlumb.repaintEverything();
                    },
                    drag: function (e, ui) {
                        jsPlumb.repaintEverything();
                    }
                });
                x.appendTo('.container');
                addConnectors(x); 
            }
            //jsPlumb.repaintEverything();
        }
    });

});

function addConnectors(x) {
    var topEndPoint = { isSource:true, isTarget:true, connector: ["Straight"],
            endpoint:['Dot', {radius:5}], outlineColor:"blue", outlineWidth:1,
            anchor:"Top", paintStyle: {fillStyle:"red"}};
    var bottomEndPoint = { isSource:true, isTarget:true, connector: ["Straight"],
            endpoint:['Dot', {radius:5}], outlineColor:"blue", outlineWidth:1,
            anchor:"Bottom", paintStyle: {fillStyle:"red"}};
            jsPlumb.addEndpoint(x, topEndPoint);
            jsPlumb.addEndpoint(x, bottomEndPoint);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question, would you mind elaborating a little bit more?

Comment: jsfiddle.net/8AgQD/62